# 3D modeling for wood working

Tags: 3d, modeling

I am looking for a program that assists in quick modeling of woodworking projects. I have some criteria.

1. Available in the future / No web interfaces (this are here today gone tomorrow and change too wildly). I want to be able to see my project as it was years from now. (also SketchUp use to be available for free and now it is not)
2. At low cost or free (I don't make any money doing these projects).
3. Supports imperial measurements (Sorry all the American tools have imperial measurement markings and its not very convenient to switch)
4. Cut list support (once the project has been completed It is necessary to see not only the bill of materials but also how you can cut these out of standard stock) This can be as simple as dimensions for each unique piece or as complex as a 4x8 piece of plywood with measurements and kirf included.

Comment: Sketch is still available for free, just not the Pro version.

Comment: @EricShain At one time I used sketchup with the cutlist add-on. It worked well enough, the problem is the basic version doesn't support any add-ons anymore (a shame), and the pro version is obscenely expensive for this purpose. I fear that the old version will no longer be available and only the web interface will be available. I used blender for my last project but there are some things that make this a bit more effort.

Comment: I'm not saying Sketchup is good for your purpose (I don't think it is), just that your statement that it is no longer free is inaccurate. You might want to look into Autodesk Fusion 360 which has a free option for some businesses with under $100K in earnings. It is very powerful.